# How to set the text for custom made toggle button android

Tags: android, android-layout, togglebutton

[image: custom toggle button]

how to add the text "on" & "off" for the toggle button ?
Do we need to add text also in image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Make your graphic larger and include the text.
2. Use a LinearLayout and incorporate two TextViews around your ImageView.
3. Subclass your overall view and draw the text in onDraw().

Comment: I like option #3. The first option borks localization and the second would use more resources than necessary. You'll want to subclass CompoundButton.

Comment: Unless you have a performance issue, I wouldn't worry about the overhead of #2.  It's probably just fine.  I agree #1 makes localization more difficult.

Comment: I have implemented the 2nd approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XML to generate the toggle button you would use `android:textOn` and `android:textOff` in your `ToggleButton<>`

Source: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html#attr_android:textOn

Comment: i don't have control to set the padding for the text. so, if i use those properties text is coming on centre, i want it to be left and right as shown in the image above.

Comment: Did you try the public attribute thumbTextPadding. This would choose the padding on either side of the switch thumb. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#thumbTextPadding